# The cornerstone definition in Abstract Elementary Classes

Tags: logic, model-theory

In the first paragraph of p.41 of [Introduction to: classification theory for abstract elementary class](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.3428.pdf), Shelah gives the following definition of (Galois) type.

> For $M\preceq N_\ell$ and $a_\ell\in N_\ell \setminus M$, $\mathbf {tp}(a_1,M,N_1)=\mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ iff for some $\preceq$-extension $N_3$ of $N_2$ there is a $\preceq$-embedding of $N_1$ into $N_3$ over $M$ which maps $a_1$ to $a_2$, recalling that $\mathfrak K_\lambda$ has amalgamation.

I have omitted references in the notation to the AEC $\mathfrak{K}_\lambda$ in which this is taking place.

How do I see that this definition is equivalent to the following definition?

> For $M\preceq N_\ell$ and $a_\ell\in N_\ell \setminus M$, $\mathbf {tp}(a_1,M,N_1)=\mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ iff there exist $\preceq$-embeddings $h: N_1\to N_3$ and $g:N_2\to N_3$ such that the resulting square commutes and $h(a_1) = g(a_2)$.

Also:

1. Why does Shelah write "recalling that $\mathfrak K_\lambda$ has amalgamation" after his definition?
2. In the definition, why does Shelah write $\mathbf{tp}_{\mathfrak{K}_\lambda}(a_1,M,N_1)=\mathbf{tp}_{\mathfrak{K}}(a_2,M,N_2)$? (Note: there is no $\lambda$ in the r.h.s.,but there is one in the l.h.s.)
3. In the second definition, do we assume that $g$ and $h$ fix $M$?

Comment: I don't understand your question - you're asking how to see that something from the first paragraph on p. 41 is equivalent to "that definition using two maps..." but it's not clear what. Could write out in detail the two statements/definitions that you want to show are equivalent?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Please, see **EDIT** in my OQ.

Comment: The question was still a total mess, so I edited it. This involved a bit of interpretation, so please make sure I maintained the intention of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These definitions are saying almost exactly the same thing. They really only differ in whether they require $N_2$ to be a substructure of $N_3$, or just embedded into it.

Suppose $\mathbf{tp}(a_1,M,N_1) = \mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ in the sense of the first definition. Then we have an extension $N_2\preceq N_3$ and a $\preceq$-embedding $h\colon N_1\to N_3$  over $M$ such that $h(a_1) = a_2$. Taking $g$ to be the inclusion $N_2\to N_3$, we find that the square commutes: for all $m\in M$, $h(m) = m = g(m)$. [This is what it means to say that $h$ is a map *over $M$*.] And $h(a_1) = a_2 = g(a_2)$. So $\mathbf{tp}(a_1,M,N_1) = \mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ in the sense of the second definition.

Conversely, suppose $\mathbf{tp}(a_1,M,N_1) = \mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ in the sense of the second definition. Then we have $\preceq$-embeddings $h\colon N_1\to N_3$ and $g\colon N_2\to N_3$ such that the resulting square commutes and $h(a_1) = g(a_2)$. Now we may assume that $N_2\preceq N_3$ and $g$ is the inclusion mapping, by replacing $N_3$ with an isomorphic copy. And then $h(a_1) = g(a_2) = a_2$, so $\mathbf{tp}(a_1,M,N_1) = \mathbf{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ in the sense of the first definition.

For your additional questions:

1. It's because a more complicated definition of Galois type turns out to be necessary in AECs without amalgamation. If the AEC lacks amalgamation, then the relation $\text{tp}(a_1,M,N_1) = \text{tp}(a_2,M,N_2)$ defined in the question (in either of the equivalent ways) might not be transitive, and hence not an equivalence relation on triples $(a,M,N)$. I believe the usual fix is just to take the transitive closure of this relation.
2. My best guess is that it's a typo.
3. I don't know what this means. We have $M\subseteq N_1$ and $h\colon N_1\to N_3$. Since $M$ is not assumed to be a subset of $N_3$, $h$ can't fix $M$. Certainly definition 2 assumes that for all $m\in M$, $h(m) = g(m)$, which is exactly what it means to say the square commutes.

Comment: Could you please correct your 4th line in which there is an incomplete notation $(a_1)=a_2$ ?

Comment: @user122424 Done

Comment: How do we find that the squares commutes in your sentence "Taking $g$ to be the inclusion $N_2→N_3$, we find that the square commutes: for all $m∈M$, $h(m)=m=g(m)$." ? More precisely how can I justify $h(m)=m$, the second equality is clear to me.

Comment: @user122424 I already explained in the bracketed comment. To say $h\colon N_1 \to N_3$ is a map *over $M$* is to say that $h$ is the identity when restricted to $M$, i.e. $h(m) = m$ for all $m\in M$. (Of course this only makes sense when $M\subseteq N_1$ and $M\subseteq N_3$).

Comment: But in the -3rd line in your item $3.$ you write $M$ is not assumed to be a subset of $N_3$ and in the above comment you write "(Of course this only makes sense when $M⊆N_1$ and $M⊆N_3$)".

Comment: @user122424 In the first definition, $M\preceq N_2\preceq N_3$, so $M\subseteq N_3$. In the second definition, $N_2$ merely $\preceq$-embeds in $N_3$, so we don't necessarily have $M\subseteq N_3$. My comment 3 was in response to your question about the second definition. This is why I wrote, in the second sentence of my answer, "[the two definitions] really only differ in whether they require $N_2$ to be a substructure of $N_3$, or just embedded into it."

Comment: Do you understand that "$N$ is a $\preceq$-extension of $M$" means that $M\preceq N$, and in particular $M$ is a substructure of $N$, while $f\colon M\to N$ is a $\preceq$-embedding means that $f$ is an embedding such that that $f(M)\preceq N$?

Comment: Now this seems clear to me, but let me have more time to meditate on it.